# nginx-rc suddenly stopping for no apparent reason - varying uptime

Tags: nginx, availability

System: Ubuntu: 20.04.1 LTS
NGINX:  nginx-rc/1.21.4.3

I am runnning nginx-rc and everytime the service will close down after a random period, I'm not running apache or any other service, I've checked all the logs and there isn't anything obvious, the service nginx-rc status gives me:

Dec 22 12:44:37 user systemd[1]: Starting The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server... Dec 22 12:44:37 user nginx-rc[17250]: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx-rc/nginx.conf syntax is ok Dec 22 12:44:37 user nginx-rc[17250]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx-rc/nginx.conf test is successful Dec 22 12:44:37 user systemd[1]: Started The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server. Dec 22 12:47:57 user systemd[1]: Stopping The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server... Dec 22 12:47:57 user systemd[1]: nginx-rc.service: Succeeded. Dec 22 12:47:57 user systemd[1]: Stopped The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.

There isn't anything in the error.log file and I've also checked the /var/log/syslog

The service can be up for anytime from a few minutes to a few hours, there isn't any consistency. I'm not too sure where to look next as I've looked at the nginx-rc server logs

Thanks